# Difficulty with VLC playing video files on Apple TV

Tags: video, appletv, vlc

Files are shared on LAN from MacOS 10.15.7 Catalina, using Home Sharing. Apple TV is model A1625 (Gen 4 I think), TvOS 17.2. VLC is ver. 3.4.9.

It's weird: I can view exactly one video file (.m4v or .mkv) per folder, exactly once. After that I can't view any file in that folder: I select a file, the VLC icon is shown along with a message "Please wait" for about one second, and then I return to the grid view of my episodes.

I turned on "Save debug logs on device" but I don't know where or what device they might be on.

Any suggestions?

**Update**

After innumerable reboots of both the ATV and the Mac, and toggling various VLC settings (ultimately not changing anything, though), the thing has decided to work. Permanently? Who knows?!

Comment: but it does play on your mac screen

Comment: @Ruskes - yes, VLC on Mac plays it fine.

Comment: OK, so it is the home sharing set up, but it confuses me that it plays only once and not anymore? you mean you can not play same file or any new files

Comment: @Ruskes - that's exactly right. I can't replay the same file, or play any new files, *within the same folder*. When I go to a folder I haven't previously visited, I can play one file once. It is very weird. I should add that I can play these files fine from VLC on my iPad.

Comment: Note update to OP. Problem not occurring.

Comment: @Chap.  Since the problem is now solved, perhaps you should add what you did as an answer (and remove it from the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Home folder permissions on the Catalina server were wrong (777). Changing them to 755 solved the problems I was having, and now VLC on AppleTV is working fine.

Solving [this problem](https://superuser.com/q/1828728/153422) with the same Catalina server is what also answered this question.